# Upstream and downstream puzzle in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Consider that I have jobs A,B,C,D in Jenkins.

Job A- contains my common code dependencies.
Job B,C,D- These are independent jobs, which refers to the dependencies in Job A.

Please note that A and B,C,D(have the upstream downstream relationship). I have added build triggers in each of them such that, each time a code is merged in GIT, it triggers the job.

The problem what I face is, Each time when the build is triggered for B, it invokes A. Now A has a list of downstream jobs C and D, it builds C and D jobs too. I want to make sure that, if B is triggered due to a commit then it should build only A and B jobs and not C and D.

I think there is a wrong configuration which i have set, kindly suggest.

I use jenkins version 1.643. Please let me know if there are plugins which can help me handle it.

Comment: It's not answering the question exactly, but in my experience getting off 1.6 and on to a 2.x version opens the doors to much better job configuration and plugin support as pipelines are supported as first class citizens

Comment: I'd second your thoughts....but upgrading it to a 2.x version is not an option for us at this point. Thanks...!!